# Entry point for a Django app which is simply a redis subscribe loop that needs access to models - no urls/views

Tags: python, django, loops, redis, publish-subscribe

I *currently* have an external non-Django python process which is a simple redis subscribe loop that simply munges the messages it receives and inserts the result in a user *mailbox* (redis list), which my main app accesses on requests.

My listener now needs access to models, so it makes sense (to me) to make this a Django app. Being a loop, however, I imagine it's probably best to run this as a separate process.

**Edit**: removed my own proposed solution using AppConfig.ready() and running the separate process via gunicorn.

What I'm doing is pretty simple, but I'm a bit confused as to where the entry point for this app should be. Any ideas?

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated,

-Scott

Comment: How is your current program receiving the messages that it stores in Redis?  If it's not through an HTTP request, you might be better off just adding an ORM like SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Not sure why you want gunicorn in this at all, given that you don't seem to need to respond to web requests. Why not something like Celery, or just a standalone management command?

Comment: @Arron Hill My *current* listener simply psubscribes to various messages published by a 3rd-tier service, and reformats them to something usable by a javascript single page app, and appends them to a redis list keyed by the userid.  the django app which is the backend to my javascript app simply pops the next message out of the redis list and serves it to the client.  Recent changes to the javascript app require that I need access to my django models when transforming messages sent via my 3rd-tier.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I see your point regarding gunicorn, as yes, there aren't any requests being served.   I suppose it still makes sense to run this in a separate process though, whether I use celery or not. So far I've only used management commands for added new command line options to manage.py.  I suppose all I really need is a script which makes use of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and then I'll have access to the models, right?

Comment: You need to call `django.setup()` before you can access/import your models.

Comment: Yes, but a management command takes care of that for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ok.  it *think* I've finally grokked this. Provided I don't run into any problems, I'll mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead with @DanielRoseman's suggested and used a management command as the entry point.

I simply added a management command 'runsubscriber' which looks like:

**my_app/management/commands/redis_subscriber.py**

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
   rsl = RedisSubcribeLoop()
   try:
      rsl.start()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      rsl.stop()
```

I can now run this as a separate process via ./manage.py runsubscriber
and kill it with a ^C.   my `stop()` looks like:

**myapp/redis_subscribe_loop.py**

```
def stop(self):
    self.rc.punsubscribe()  # unsubscribe from all channels
    self.rc.close()
```

so that it shuts down cleanly.

Thanks for all your help,

-Scott